# Geo Nodes Affect Flower separately from the stem

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made this wind effect for grass using geometry nodes (blender 3.4), and because I am new in this I stucked with part, where I need to add wind effect for the flower part separately, to make it look more natural.
How to make this node tree [image] control flower part separately?

Here is the current result I have [(youtube video link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2RwYRaSt74)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I cannot see in your screenshot how this is affecting the flowers, stems or anything, but I guess a simple way would be to use this wind setup for the stems and create another one with different parameters to affect the flowers. That's the quick and dirty way.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: maybe you zoomed in too far...? :D

Comment: @Chris Pardon? Don't know what you mean... I only see Position, Vector Add, Noise + Musgrave Texture, Subtract and Scale node. Can't see how the stems and flowers are connected to that or how they are created...

Comment: It was just a joke….that’s why I added the „ :D“

Comment: You should be nice - he has > 300K followers - maybe he hires you in the future….

Comment: @Chris He is "the future of 3D animation", I'm confident he will get along without me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this kind of node setup:

[image]

so you can plugin the boolean capture attribute into set position to see the difference:

[image]